# Expandable ListView with JSON Data in android

Tags: android, json, dynamic-data, expandablelistview

I have a big problem and I have been searching on the web to have a good solution for this problem but I couldn't find any approach for this problem so I want help.

I need to use expandable list view which get data from server (JSON Array) and i have categories, `GroupData` and its items, `ChildData`. I don't know how to get the child data for each parent group... i need something like `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` but i didn't find anything.

This is what i reach for till now but it's not working so please help me:

```
      static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapList = 
          new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> catItemsList = 
          new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  static ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> ItemsList = 
          new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
  static   ListView order_list;
  static ExpandableListView order_items_list;
  static  SimpleAdapter adapter,ItemsAdapter;


protected void BindOrederItemList(final int order_id) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //select all categories from order items where order_id =??
        //select items where category=??

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        //int    no_pepole=Integer.valueOf(noOfGest_txt.getText().toString());
            try
            {
        //  params.put("order_status",myStatus);
         int rest_id=prefs.getInt("Rest_id", 0);
            params.put("order_id", order_id);
            params.put("lang_id", 1);
            params.put("rest_id", rest_id );
            //params.put("order_status", 0);
        //  params.put("noOfpepole",number_of_guest);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        String Url="http://192.168.3.113/mywebservices.php?op=GetOrderCategory";
        GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener listener=new GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (result!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                     catItemsList.clear();
                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                 ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> list=new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
               //  ArrayList<Integer> category=new ArrayList<Integer>();

                 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 

                    {
                      HashMap<String, String> Catmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            id=e.getInt("order_id");

                         cat_name=e.getString("cat_name");
                          cat_id=e.getInt("cat_id");
                          Catmap.put("cat_id",String.valueOf(cat_id));
                          Catmap.put("cat_name", cat_name);
                          catItemsList.add(Catmap);
                          Log.i("Insid For Loop", "order ID "+order_id);

                          list=  BindCatItems(cat_id, order_id);
                        Log.i("Insid For Loop", "Child size = "+list.size());
                    }
               // Log.i("Insid For Loop", "Group size = "+catItemsList.size());


                 SimpleExpandableListAdapter expandListAdapter= new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), 
                         catItemsList,  R.layout.group_item, 
                          new String[] {"cat_name"},new int[]{R.id.lbl_cat_group},
                           list, R.layout.category_row, new String[]{"item_name"}, new int[]{R.id.txt_category_row});


                 order_items_list.setAdapter(expandListAdapter);
                      //  Log.i("Bind item", "CAT SIZE "+catItemsList.size());

                        }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        };

        try
        {
        GetNetworkData task = new GetNetworkData(Url,params,listener);
        task.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    protected ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> BindCatItems(int cat_id,int order_id)

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        //int    no_pepole=Integer.valueOf(noOfGest_txt.getText().toString());
            try
            {
        //  params.put("order_status",myStatus);
         int rest_id=prefs.getInt("Rest_id", 0);
            params.put("order_id", order_id);
            params.put("lang_id", 1);
            params.put("cat_id",cat_id );
            //params.put("order_status", 0);
        //  params.put("noOfpepole",number_of_guest);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        String Url="http://192.168.3.113/mywebservices.php?op=GetOrderItems";
        GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener listener=new GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener() 

        {

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (result!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Log.i("log bind","Inside Bind Category items");
                        // catItemsList.clear();
                        mapList.clear();
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 
                            {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id=e.getInt("item_id");
                                if (id==0)
                                {

                                }


                                else
                                {

                                map.put("item_id",String.valueOf(e.getInt("item_id")));
                                map.put("oi_id", String.valueOf(e.getInt("oi_id")));
                                map.put("item_name", e.getString("item_name"));
                                map.put("quantity",String.valueOf( e.getString("quantity")));
                                map.put("price", String.valueOf("price"));
                       mapList.add(map);

                                }
                            }
                            ItemsList.add(mapList);
                         //   Log.i("Bind Item Order", "CAT SIZE "+catItemsList.size());



                           /*  ItemsAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), catItemsList, 
                                    R.layout.list_item,
                                    new String[] {"item_name"},
                                    new int[]{R.id.list_item_title});
                           */
                           //  Log.i("Add Section","ItemsAdapter count= "+ItemsAdapter.getCount());


                             //order_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        try
        {
        GetNetworkData task = new GetNetworkData(Url,params,listener);
        task.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return ItemsList;


    }
```

Comment: can you make a beans of your json and add them to arrayList this way you will have to use jst one list to update childView and groupView.The childView and parentview works the same way as getView from adapter for ListView

Comment: could you please explain more about  (beans of your json )and give me an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation, SimpleExpandableListAdapter is for static data. What is happening here is probably that your methods are returning before the data is fetched and the listener passed to the AsyncTask is called after the adapter has already been created.

So, the first thing I'd recommend to try is fetch the data first, and once the two listeners are executed ( by checking your own defined boolean flags or lists' lengths ), define the adapter and pass it to the ListView.

Comment: ok i'll try you recommendation but the thing that stopped me is that how to get child for the group ..i mean if i have four groups with IDs(1,2,3,4) how to get its child where parent ID =1 and 2,... and so.do you got my point.now i have the list only with the groups but it's child didn't bind

Comment: It depends on your use case.
If the whole list with its children have to be present, then you'll have to fetch all categories' children in a loop. ( Another thing I noted in your code, the child items should be a list of a list, a list for each group ).
If the users are more likely to expand only one or two groups, then maybe you should create a custom adapter and load children when a group is expanded only.

Comment: what is the meaning of list of list could give me an example coz i have now this exception 05-08 13:38:42.660: E/AndroidRuntime(31012): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: Instead of `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` you should declare it as `ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>`. Each list has the child items of a single group.

Comment: @ Hassan Ibraheem really i don't know how could i thank you ,this help me allot ,Thanks for your response and i'll edit my code and post it again to see it ..Thanks

Comment: I edit my answer and I have now only one problem that is all parents have the same child list of the last parent ..Could you see my code

Comment: The reason is that you're using the same mapList object for each category, so when you `mapList.clear();` you're clearing the last category's items and adding the new ones instead, so the ItemsList will hold entries for the same object. Create a new mapList for each category, or even better or make it a local reference within method scope.

Comment: @ Hassan Thank you it's now solving really i don't know how to thank you

Answer (score 0):

i put you here my solution for handle two json using lisview;

```
public class ListViewer extends ListActivity{
    //Primary URL JSON1
    private static String url0 = "http:/a.com/url";
    //URL JSON2
    private static String url2 = "http:/a.com/url";

    //JSON1 Node names
    public static final String TAG_COURSES1 = "Courses";           //JSONArray from json1
    public static final String TAG_COURSEID1 = "CourseId";         //Object from json1 - Array courses
    public static final String TAG_RATING1 = "Rating";             //Object from json1 - Array courses
    public static final String TAG_STATUS1 = "Status";             //Object from json1 - Array courses  
    // JSON2 Node names
    public static final String TAG_COURSES2 = "Courses";           //JSONArray from json2
    public static final String TAG_COURSEID2 = "CourseId";         //Object from json2 - Array courses
    public static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";                //Object from json2 - Array courses
    public static final String TAG_INSTRUCTOR = "instructor";      //Object from json2 - Array courses
    public static final String TAG_LENGTH = "length";              //Object from json2 - Array courses
    public static final String TAG_RATING2 = "Rating";             //Object from json2 - Array courses
    public static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";            //Object from json2 - Array courses
    public static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";    //Object from json2 - Array courses
    public static final String txt_instructor = "Instructor: ";
    public static final String txt_length = "Length: ";
    public static final String txt_minutes = "minutes";

    //Course JSONArray's from json1 & json2 = null, for now.
    JSONArray Courses1 = null;
    JSONArray Courses2 = null;

    //Lists
    public ListView list1;
    public ListView list2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lay_main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> coursesList1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> coursesList2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        //Getting bundles 3 & 4, from MariposaTrainingActivity.class...
        Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        String userName=bundle1.getString("UN");   //Getting the userName
        Bundle bundle2 = getIntent().getExtras();
        String password=bundle2.getString("PW");   //Getting the passord
        String UR = "UserName=";                   //String for build the url1, for the request json1.
        String QTE = "&";                          //String for build the url1, for the request json1.
        String PW = "Password=";                   //String for build the url1, for the request json1.
        //Building the URL to get the json1.
        String url1 = url0 + UR + userName + QTE + PW + password;

        // Creating JSON Parser instance (json1)
        JSONParser2 jParser1 = new JSONParser2();
        // getting JSON string from URL (json1)
        final JSONObject json1 = jParser1.getJSONFromUrl(url1);

        // Creating JSON Parser instance (json2)
        JSONParser2 jParser2 = new JSONParser2();
        // getting JSON string from URL (json2)
        final JSONObject json2 = jParser2.getJSONFromUrl(url2);                                         

                try {           
                    // Getting The Array "Courses" from json1 & json2   
                    Courses1 =json1.getJSONArray(TAG_COURSES1);
                    Courses2 = json2.getJSONArray(TAG_COURSES2);
                    int x = 1;
                    //LOOP FOR JSON1
                    for(int i = 0; i < Courses1.length(); i++){
                        //LOOP FOR JSON2
                        for(int ii = 0; ii < Courses2.length(); ii++){
                            JSONObject courses1 = Courses1.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject courses2 = Courses2.getJSONObject(ii);

                            // Storing each json1 item in variable
                            int courseID1 = courses1.getInt(TAG_COURSEID1);
                            //Log.e("COURSEID1:", Integer.toString(courseID1));
                            String Rating1 = courses1.getString(TAG_RATING1);
                            int Status1 = courses1.getInt(TAG_STATUS1);
                            //Log.e("Status1:", Integer.toString(Status1));      //Put the actual value for Status1 in log.             

                            // Storing each json2 item in variable
                            int courseID2 = courses2.getInt(TAG_COURSEID2);
                            //Log.e("COURSEID2:", Integer.toString(courseID2));   //Put the actual value for CourseID2 in log
                            String Title2 = courses2.getString(TAG_TITLE);                      
                            String instructor2 = courses2.getString(TAG_INSTRUCTOR);
                            String length2 = courses2.getString(TAG_LENGTH);
                            String rating2 = courses2.getString(TAG_RATING2);
                            String subject2 = courses2.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                            String description2 = courses2.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);

                            //Status1 = 5 from json1; Incomplete, Status1 =-1 Complete 
                            if(courseID2 == courseID1){             
                            int x1 = x++; //Get the count for All values.
                            //Log.e("x=", Integer.toString(x1)); //Show the value in Logcat.
                            // Get pairs/odds.
                            int Num = x1 % 2;
                            //Log.e("Num=", Integer.toString(Num)); //
                            //Creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            if(Num==1){

                                    map.put(TAG_COURSEID2, Integer.toString(courseID2));
                                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, Title2);
                                    map.put(txt_instructor, "Instructor: ");
                                    map.put(TAG_INSTRUCTOR, instructor2);
                                    map.put(txt_length, "Length: ");
                                    map.put(TAG_LENGTH, length2);
                                    map.put(txt_minutes, " minutes");
                                    map.put(TAG_RATING2, rating2);
                                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject2);
                                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description2);

                                    //adding HashList to ArrayList
                                    coursesList1.add(map);
                            }
                            if(Num==0)
                            {

                                    map2.put(TAG_COURSEID2, Integer.toString(courseID2));
                                    map2.put(TAG_TITLE, Title2);
                                    map2.put(txt_instructor, "Instructor: ");
                                    map2.put(TAG_INSTRUCTOR, instructor2);
                                    map2.put(txt_length, "Length: ");
                                    map2.put(TAG_LENGTH, length2);
                                    map2.put(txt_minutes, " minutes");
                                    map2.put(TAG_RATING2, rating2);
                                    map2.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject2);
                                    map2.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description2);

                                    //adding HashList to ArrayList
                                    coursesList2.add(map2);
                             }
                            }//if
                        }//for2 (json2)
                    } //for1 (json1)                
                }//Try
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                
                    }

        ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(this, coursesList2,
                R.layout.list_courses_2,
                new String[] { TAG_COURSEID2, TAG_TITLE, txt_instructor, TAG_INSTRUCTOR, txt_length, TAG_LENGTH, txt_minutes, TAG_RATING2, TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_DESCRIPTION }, new int[] {
                        R.id.txt_courseid_r2, R.id.txt_title_r2, R.id.txt_text_instructor_r2, R.id.txt_instructor_r2, R.id.txt_text_length_r2,R.id.txt_length_r2, R.id.txt_text_minutes_r2,R.id.txt_rating_r2, R.id.txt_topic_r2, R.id.txt_description_r2 });
        setListAdapter(adapter2);
        colectorXML2();
        list2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        list2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String courseID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_courseid_r2)).getText().toString();
                String Title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_r2)).getText().toString();
                String instructor = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_instructor_r2)).getText().toString();
                String length = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_length_r2)).getText().toString();
                String rating = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_rating_r2)).getText().toString();
                String subject = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_topic_r2)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_description_r2)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_COURSEID2, courseID);
                in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, Title);
                in.putExtra(TAG_INSTRUCTOR, instructor);
                in.putExtra(TAG_LENGTH, length);
                in.putExtra(TAG_RATING2, rating);
                in.putExtra(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });//lv.SetOnclickListener

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, coursesList1,
                R.layout.list_courses,
                new String[] { TAG_COURSEID2, TAG_TITLE, txt_instructor, TAG_INSTRUCTOR, txt_length, TAG_LENGTH, txt_minutes, TAG_RATING2, TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_DESCRIPTION }, new int[] {
                        R.id.txt_courseid, R.id.txt_title, R.id.txt_text_instructor, R.id.txt_instructor, R.id.txt_text_length,R.id.txt_length, R.id.txt_text_minutes,R.id.txt_rating, R.id.txt_topic, R.id.txt_description });
        colectorXML();      
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String courseID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_courseid)).getText().toString();
                String Title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title)).getText().toString();
                String instructor = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_instructor)).getText().toString();
                String length = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_length)).getText().toString();
                String rating = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_rating)).getText().toString();
                String subject = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_topic)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_description)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_COURSEID2, courseID);
                in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, Title);
                in.putExtra(TAG_INSTRUCTOR, instructor);
                in.putExtra(TAG_LENGTH, length);
                in.putExtra(TAG_RATING2, rating);
                in.putExtra(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });//lv.SetOnclickListener       
    }//onCreate

    private void colectorXML() {
        list1 = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }
    private void colectorXML2() {
        list2 =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);  
    }   
}// Activity
```

Just put your methods, and your json info, in this case you just handle 1 json, so make the rest... Hope this give you ideas.

Answer (score 0):

i have solve the problem after this good help from all and here is the answer

```
        protected void BindOrederItemList(final int order_id) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //select all categories from order items where order_id =??
        //select items where category=??

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        //int    no_pepole=Integer.valueOf(noOfGest_txt.getText().toString());
            try
            {
        //  params.put("order_status",myStatus);
         int rest_id=prefs.getInt("Rest_id", 0);
            params.put("order_id", order_id);
            params.put("lang_id", 1);
            params.put("rest_id", rest_id );
            //params.put("order_status", 0);
        //  params.put("noOfpepole",number_of_guest);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        String Url="http://192.168.3.113/mywebservices.php?op=GetOrderCategory";
        GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener listener=new GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (result!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                     catItemsList.clear();
                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                 ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> list=new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
               //  ArrayList<Integer> category=new ArrayList<Integer>();

                 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 

                    {
                      HashMap<String, String> Catmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            id=e.getInt("order_id");

                         cat_name=e.getString("cat_name");
                          cat_id=e.getInt("cat_id");
                          Catmap.put("cat_id",String.valueOf(cat_id));
                          Catmap.put("cat_name", cat_name);
                          catItemsList.add(Catmap);
                          Log.i("Insid For Loop", "order ID "+order_id);

                          list=  BindCatItems(cat_id, order_id);



                        Log.i("Insid For Loop", "Child size = "+list.size());
                    }
               // Log.i("Insid For Loop", "Group size = "+catItemsList.size());

                 SimpleExpandableListAdapter expandListAdapter= new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), 
                          catItemsList,  R.layout.group_item, 
                          new String[] {"cat_name"},new int[]{R.id.lbl_cat_group},
                          BindCatItems(cat_id, order_id), R.layout.category_row, new String[]{"item_name"}, new int[]{R.id.txt_category_row});


                 order_items_list.setAdapter(expandListAdapter);
                      //  Log.i("Bind item", "CAT SIZE "+catItemsList.size());

                        }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        };

        try
        {
        GetNetworkData task = new GetNetworkData(Url,params,listener);
        task.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    protected ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> BindCatItems(int cat_id,int order_id)

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ItemsList.clear();
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

        //int    no_pepole=Integer.valueOf(noOfGest_txt.getText().toString());
            try
            {
        //  params.put("order_status",myStatus);
         int rest_id=prefs.getInt("Rest_id", 0);
            params.put("order_id", order_id);
            params.put("lang_id", 1);
            params.put("cat_id",cat_id );
            //params.put("order_status", 0);
        //  params.put("noOfpepole",number_of_guest);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        String Url="http://192.168.3.113/mywebservices.php?op=GetOrderItems";
        GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener listener=new GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener() 

        {

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (result!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Log.i("log bind","Inside Bind Category items");
                        // catItemsList.clear();
                         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapList = 
                                  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 
                            {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id=e.getInt("item_id");
                                if (id==0)
                                {

                                }


                                else
                                {



                                map.put("item_id",String.valueOf(e.getInt("item_id")));
                                map.put("oi_id", String.valueOf(e.getInt("oi_id")));
                                map.put("item_name", e.getString("item_name"));
                                map.put("quantity",String.valueOf( e.getString("quantity")));
                                map.put("price", String.valueOf("price"));
                       mapList.add(map);

                                }
                            }

                            ItemsList.add(mapList);

                         //   Log.i("Bind Item Order", "CAT SIZE "+catItemsList.size());



                           /*  ItemsAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), catItemsList, 
                                    R.layout.list_item,
                                    new String[] {"item_name"},
                                    new int[]{R.id.list_item_title});
                           */
                           //  Log.i("Add Section","ItemsAdapter count= "+ItemsAdapter.getCount());


                             //order_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        try
        {
        GetNetworkData task = new GetNetworkData(Url,params,listener);
        task.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return ItemsList;


    }
```